# ajax pulling a php file

Tags: cakephp, jquery

I'm using cakephp. I have an ajax request that is pulling a php file to be displayed.
The problem I'm having is that the php file that is being pulled needs to execute php code before it is pulled. It's cakephp code that creates a form. At the moment the php file is being displayed as it is in the file rather than the html it is meant to change to if i view it directly through the browser.

I'm not sure how to overcome this. Any ideas?
Many Thanks

**CODE**
Jquery -

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/files/Users/"+name+".ctp",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $('#pageLoading p').html('We have experienced a problem. Please try again later.');
            return false;
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            sortData(msg);
        }
```

Part of php file (actually a .ctp file but it has .php code in it) -

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
$options = array(
'label' => ' ',
'id' => 'formSubmit',
'class' => 'userSubmit',
'div' => FALSE
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
```

With cakephp this php is displayed as a html for however when i grab it with ajax and print it on the screen it is displayed as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic idea seems to be faulty: don't fetch a `.ctp` file directly but stick to the controller/view idea.
So instead create a controller method in your `Users` controller

```
public function show_form($name){
}
```

Make sure you have a matching view file ready containing the form code. E.g. `View/Users/show_form.ctp`.

Next: make sure your script calls: `http://example.com/users/show_form/the_name`

Answer (score 1):

`url: "/files/Users/"+name+".ctp",`

looks wrong to me.

You need to pass in the `controller/action` so that Cake executes and parses the view file properly.

Also `$this->layout = 'ajax';` might be handy; so you don't end up with your "main" layouts html code in the response.